# Components of electromagnetic complex plane waves

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

Short question on *electromagnetic waves*. I am interested to know why the $z$ component of the complex monochromatic plane wave of the electric part of an electromagnetic wave is zero.
If we consider the monochromatic planar electric wave $$\mathbf{\tilde{E}}(z,t) = \mathbf{\tilde{E}}_0e^{i(kz- \omega t)},$$ where $\mathbf{\tilde{E}_0} = \vec{\mathbf{E}}e^{i \delta}$ is the complex amplitude.

Is the reason that $(\tilde{E})_{z} = 0$ because Gauss's law $\nabla \cdot \vec{\mathbf{E}} = 0$ implies $$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{\tilde{E}} = \nabla \cdot[\vec{E}e^{i(kz-\omega t + \delta)}] = E_{z}(ik)e^{i(kz- \omega t + \delta)}=0\implies(E_{z}) = 0\implies(\tilde{E}_{z}) = 0?$$

Is this the correct reasoning? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's pretty much it. That's why that happens.

Just to make this longer than a one-liner: note that an identification of the form $\widetilde{\mathbf E}_0=\vec{\mathbf E}e^{i\delta}$ sort of misses the point of complex amplitudes, since $\delta$ is ill-defined, and there's no guarantee that you can make $\vec{\mathbf E}$ real-valued. How would you deal, for example, with $\widetilde{\mathbf E}=|E_0|e^{i\delta}(\hat{\mathbf e}_x+ i\hat{\mathbf e}_y)$?

Comment: In the book I am using (which is introductory), it seems to suggest that the electric field $\mathbf{\vec{E}}$ is a real-valued vector field, are the components more generally complex valued? Also, how is $\delta$ ill-defined exactly?

Comment: Your book is wrong (or you are misinterpreting it). There is generally no way to make all the components of $\vec {\mathbf E}$ real-valued simultaneously; the counterexample is the circularly polarized wave at the end of my answer. This is why $\delta$ is ill-defined.

Comment: Just to be clear though, when dealing with electric fields which originate from stationary charges, we consider the electric field as being real valued?

Comment: The physical fields are *always* real-valued. The field you wrote down, $\mathbf{\tilde{E}}(z,t) = \mathbf{\tilde{E}}_0e^{i(kz- \omega t)},$ is not physical - you get to the physical field by taking the real part. For further small questions along this line, though, it's better to ask on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).

Comment: I sent a question on chat, not sure if you received it. So real part of what I wrote $Re[\mathbf{\tilde{E}}] = Re[\mathbf{\vec{E}}e^{i(kz-\omega t + \delta)}] = \mathbf{\vec{E}}\cos(kz-\omega t + \delta)$ where $\mathbf{\vec{E}}$ is real valued since we got it by taking the real part of $\mathbf{\tilde{E}}$. But you are saying that $\mathbf{\vec{E}}$ is not necessarily real, what is wrong the with what I stated? Thanks.
 I think you have a typo in your answer. Did you mean "there's no guarantee you can make $\mathbf{\tilde{E}}$ real"?

Comment: @JohnDoe The answer is correct as stated. The identification into a cosine in your comment is wrong since $\vec{\mathbf E}$ need not be real; again, try it with the example I provide and see why it breaks. (In essence, there's no requirement that the $x$ and $y$ components of the physical field be in phase, which is what the $i$ before the $\hat{\mathbf e}_y$ represents. For future reference, it's not particularly OK to badger people in this way; by 'ask on chat' I meant 'ask on chat and see if anyone is around to answer.

Comment: I understand what you are saying since working through your example I would get $Re[\mathbf{\tilde{E}}] = |E_{0}|(\cos(\delta) \hat{x}-\sin(\delta)\hat{y})$ which cannot be written in the form $\vec{E}\cos(...)$ where $\vec{E}$ is real. So my proof is a special case I guess, how do you advise I improve my proof above to generalize it?

Comment: You don't. That's why we have the complex-valued forms - they let us deal with that without the hassle. You say $\mathbf{\tilde{E}}(z,t) = \mathbf{\tilde{E}}_0 e^{i(kz- \omega t)},$ you note that $\mathbf{\tilde{E}}_0$ is a complex-valued vector amplitude, you note that the physical field is $\mathrm{Re}(\mathbf{\tilde{E}}(z,t))$, and you move on.

Comment: This site's format is not well suited for this sort of back-and-forth, and it is not OK to keep asking the same questions as comments. If you want this kind of interaction, look in the chatroom to see if someone is available. This is my last comment on this thread. I may or may not be available later for further dicussions on chat.

Comment: Okay no prob, have a good day!